# Excel VBA: 'excel vba run-time error 1004' application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: debugging, excel, compiler-errors, vba

I have this line in a module and it keeps spitting up a run-time error 1004 when I try and run it.

Can anyone help?

I'm guessing it's to do with how the Range is referenced, but i'm not sure. This is all new to me.

```
rngFirst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Still In Progress").Range("G" & 1 & ":G" & lw)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a sheet called 'Still In Progress'? - and is that 'ell doubleyew' after `":G" &`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim rngFirst As Range
Dim int1 As Integer

int1 = 2

Set rngFirst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & 1 & ":G" & int1)

rngFirst.Select

End Sub
```

I was getting the same error as you until I used Dim and Set.

Answer (score 1):

Your range is not defined correctly.  Essentially, you are setting the range to:

"Still In Progress!G1:G1w".

You need to set the last bit of the rngFirst formula to a number (eg at the bottom right hand corner of the range).  Something like:

`...Range("G" & 1 & ":G" & 20)`

if the bottom of your data is at row 20.